# Parsing a certain table from Wikipedia using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to extract the information from a particular table in Wikipedia by using `DOMDocumen`t in PHP.

I'm building a NFL players database, and I'm trying to include the table that's titled "Career NFL Statistics since xx/xx/xx"

The code is

```
<?php
    $html_text = file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/".$FName['FName']."%20".$LName['LName']);
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->validateOnParse = true;
    $xml->loadHTML($html_text);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
    $table =$xpath->query("//table")->item(1);
    print $xml->saveXML($table);
?>
```

This works for some players, but other players with wikipedia pages like Cam Newton's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cam_Newton) the code returns a different table.

Is there another way to select the table that begins with "Career NFL Statistics...."? Wikipedia doesn't have id tags, so i'm at a loss.

Comment: `//h2[span[starts-with(text(), "NFL career statistics")]]//following-sibling::table[contains(@class,"wikitable")]`

Comment: That doesn't work, I get some PHP error. This was the code I used        
        `//h2[span[starts-with(text(), "Career NFL statistics")]]//following-sibling::table[contains(@class,"infobox")]"`

Comment: I believe I may have solved it! This was the code that I used `//tr[starts-with(., 'Career NFL')]//following-sibling::tr`